# Unable to get rootState in getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Why does this simple getter in a Vuex module fail to do what [API reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html) says?

```
const getters = {
  myGetRootState: (state, rootState) => {
    return rootState
  }
}
```

Getter above returns current module state, not store state.

And this

```
const getters = {
  myGetRootState: rootState => {
    return console.log(rootState.anyModuleYouWant)
  }
}
```

Logs undefined. I've tried many permutations of context and return values, to no avail.

Any idea why this is and how to get it to do what is intended?

Answer (score 2):

The module getter takes 3 arguments (Local state, getters, root state).

```
 const getters = {

   myGetRootState (state, getters, rootState){
    console.log("rootState.exampleVar = "+ rootState.exampleVar)
    return rootState.exampleVar
   }
}
```

Use in a Vue instance component:

```
computed: {
   myGetRootState: function(){
            return this.$store.getters.myGetRootState
        }
}
```

You don't need to specify the module in your Vue instance.